Receiving calls stops working on the iPhone after a while React Native twilio
I am using twilio-voice-react-native@1.0.0 and  testing calls from Android to iOS. The call is received on the iPhone while in the foreground and background. However, after some calls, it stops working in the app's killed state on the iPhone. I delete the app from the iPhone and then reinstall it. The call works fine again on the iPhone in the killed state, but after some calls, no call is received in the app's killed state. The call always works fine in the foreground.
In xcode project in sigining and capbilities background modes on for Voip.That why app works fine for a while.
I have integrated the sentry Where received error related to voip
NSInternalInconsistencyException: Killing app because it never posted an incoming call to the system after receiving a PushKit VoIP push.
I am not sure how this is the cause and how to fix.
Iphone app should receive the call while in killed state every time
Calling device Android pixel 6 android 13 "react-native": "0.72.6",
Receiving device iPhone 15 with ios version 17+. "react-native": "0.72.6",
